# Django admin change to_python output based on request

Tags: django, forms, encryption, admin, field

I'm wondering how to change the behavior of a form field based on data in the request... especially as it relates to the Django Admin.  For example, I'd like to decrypt a field in the admin based on request data (such as POST or session variables).

My thoughts are to start looking at overriding the change_view method in django/contrib/admin/options.py, since that has access to the request.  However, I'm not sure how to affect how the field value displays the field depending on some value in the request.  If the request has the correct value, the field value would be displayed; otherwise, the field value would return something like "NA".

My thought is that if I could somehow get that request value into the to_python() method, I could directly impact how the field is displayed. Should I try passing the request value into the form **init** and then somehow into the field **init**?  Any suggestions how I might approach this?

Thanks for reading.

In models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    hidden_data = models.CharField()
```

In admin.py

```
class MyModelAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta: 
        model = MyModel

def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
    .... # Perhaps this is where I'd do a lot of overriding? 
    ....
    return self.render_change_form(request, context, change=True, obj=obj)
```

Comment: just to clarify, you want to manipulate the value of a particular field in a particular model visible (via the admin), depending on something in the request?

Comment: One more point I should clarify is that I don't want the stored value to change.  Simply the display of that value would change.

Comment: That might be further complicated by the fact that the admin renders the forms as ModelForms, meaning the objects value is bound to the field, making it difficult to change the value without it being saved back to the object. You would have to change the value in the form field 'on the way out' (i.e. when displaying) and make sure to change it back 'on the way in' (i.e. when saving)

Comment: Ya, I see what you mean.  In my situation, I suppose I only need it to be read-only.  "user somehow authenticates and is able to see more private info... an extra layer on top of Django auth." But maybe would be easier to use django groups and some custom templates to restrict on the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but you could just overwrite the `render_change_form` method of the `ModelAdmin` to sneak in your code to change the field value between when the `change_view` is processed and the actual template rendered

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def render_change_form(self, request, context, **kwargs):
        # Here we have access to the request, the object being displayed and the context which contains the form
        form = content['adminform'].form
        field = form.fields['field_name']
        ...
        if 'obj' in kwargs:
            # Existing obj is being saved
        else:
            # New object is being created (an empty form)
        return super(MyModelAdmin).render_change_form(request, context, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'll take a look into that render_change_form method.  Seems like a good way to hook into the admin.  Thank you for this advice.